# ETW - Why sometimes ETL does not have valid manifest schema

Tags: etw

I have configured a collector set that also collects ETW trace. Result is ETL file.
Sometimes when I get a ETL file I do not have valid manifest and only what I see in events are guids. I can dump event and see the content, but I cannot see all columns and so on...

[image: Screenshot]

Sometimes it is all good. Provider names are valid, as well as data. The only difference is when it works, in event providers I have also ProviderName/ManifestData.

How can I set it up to always have manifest data?

Comment: do you get a message that events are lost when you open the ETL?

Comment: No, I did not. Everything looks fine.